# Stress-energy tensor of a $2\text{d}$ conformal field theory

Tags: conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, noethers-theorem

Does stress-energy tensor of a $2\text{d}$ conformal field theory split into holomorphic and anti-holomorphic parts as follows?

In a conformal field theory, stress-energy tensor $$T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$$ is traceless as a consequence of the invariance of $S$ under a Weyl transformation $\delta g^{\mu\nu} = \epsilon g^{\mu\nu}$, i.e

$$\delta S \propto T_{\mu\nu}\delta g^{\mu\nu} = \epsilon T_{\mu\nu} g^{\mu\nu}  = T^\mu_\mu\rightarrow T^\mu_\mu = 0\tag{1}$$

Which implies $T_{z\bar{z}} = T_{\bar{z}z} = 0$ in complex coordinates. Denoting $T(z) = T_{zz}$ and $\bar{T}(\bar{z}) = T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}$,  our stress-energy tensor reads

$$[T] =\begin{pmatrix}T_{zz} & T_{z\bar{z}} \\ T_{\bar{z}z} & T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}T(z) & 0 \\ 0 & \bar{T}(\bar{z})\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

Where holomorphic $T(z)$ and anti-holomorphic $\bar{T}(\bar{z})$ components admit a Laurent expansion

$$T(z) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}L_nz^{-n-2}\quad\space L_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\vert z\vert = 1} \frac{T(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\tag{3}$$

$$\bar{T}(\bar{z}) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\bar{L}_n\bar{z}^{-n-2}\quad\space \bar{L}_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\vert \bar{z}\vert = 1} \frac{\bar{T}(\bar{z})}{\bar{z}^{n+1}}d\bar{z}\tag{4}$$